# Looking to create a complex gradient design, preferably as a vector

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, gradient

[image: Image of mock up print]

I'm a fashion student and I'm designing a print for a piece of knitwear I am producing. I was wondering if anyone would know how to reproduce a gradient along the lines of the mock up attached. I would prefer it to be as a vector but am open to any method. Basically it wants to be a lot more accurate and with sharper corners, whilst still fading smoothly at its inner edges. Thanks!

Comment: along the lines of the mock up attached-- you mean the border? outline of the body?

Comment: Could be done in Illustrator with meshes.. not easily though.

Comment: Sorry poor wording on my part. Just like the blue gradient design.

Comment: Are you at all familiar with *any* vector tools? Have you explored any software? We have no idea hat your level of proficiency may be. If you have no experience at all, you'll need to start searching for tutorials in whatever app you want to use. UI know it can be done as vector in Illustrator. However, I'm sure Inkscape, or Xara, or others could do something similar.

Comment: I have had some luck with using gradient meshes, I might get away with just using a mask with blur afterwards because it's still sort of an unclean method to get the desired effect. It just feels like it should be so much more obvious because the final effect is so "simple". (I am relatively familiar with illustrator, I have used it often for a few years now)